# How is quantum information stored in the universe?

Tags: quantum-information

Law of conservation of quantum information states that quantum information can neither be created nor destroyed. Then, how is it stored in the universe? How can we access that quantum information?

Answer (score 1):

Quantum information is stored in the quantum wave function of the whole universe (in fact, you could say it *is* the quantum wave function of the whole universe). However, because we cannot observe the quantum wave function of the whole universe, we cannot access most of this information. If we observe a small part of the universe (say we measure the state of a qubit in a quantum computer) then we cause the wave function for that part of the universe to collapse. The information that was apparently "lost" in wave function collapse has in fact dissipated into other parts of the universe (the "environment") - so the information is conserved, but is no longer easily accessible. For more information see [this Wikipedia article on the no-hiding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hiding_theorem).